# import local .css.less file with rails 3.1 + less-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, less

Using rails 3.1 and less-rails (>= 2.1.1):

Is anyone out there successfully using @import to include local .css.less files?  I'm using the following file structure to try to do so:

application.css:

```
//= require less
```

less.css.less:

```
@import "layout"
```

layout.css.less:

```
body {
  background-color: white;
}
```

However the contents of layout.css.less never get loaded. I also tried importing "layout.css" and "layout.css.less" to no avail.

I know that less.css.less gets loaded because if I put some css in there, it gets loaded.

I'm using @import to include the layout.css.less file because (ultimately) I'm trying to use the asset helper image-url, and the author of less-rails told me I need to use @import [here](https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails/issues/14)

UPDATE:

I added a semicolon to the @import statements, and now rather than nothing from the less.css.less file being loaded, I see the @import statements themselves in the loaded stylesheet.

Comment: I got this working by renaming the layout.css.less file to layout.less

Comment: Can you please answer the question and mark it as answered.  It's showing up as unanswered right now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working by renaming the layout.css.less file to layout.less

Comment: I had the same issue, but I was trying to import regular CSS files into LESS file using @import directive. Thank you very much! Renaming to *.less fixed it all!